# page not centered in Ipad

Tags: css, ipad, html

Site seems to work good in all browsers,
but is not centering on the Ipad.

this is the [page](http://www.reyescaballerorey.com/voodoo_page/)

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Thanks!!!

Comment: maybe edit in your css and some html, how you make the page so its easier to help. Nobody will go to your page, look up for source, download css and then try find a fix.

Answer (score 0):

**you should use % and em for defining width you are using px.**

you have width defined on the body by:

```
body 
{
     line-height:0;
     min-width:1366px;
}
```

and many elements.

search for [Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493158/adaptive-layouts-in-css3/12493709#12493709)

Comment: Thank you guys,  I tried with % but now it doesnt work on iphone

Answer (score 0):

Decrease the size of your **#container** DIV to **800px**.

Write like this:

```
body 
{
     line-height:0;
     min-width:800px;
}
div#container{
 width:800px;
}
```